# problem setting up rails 3 app with mysql2 0.2.11 and rake 0.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, mysql2

I have a project with the following Gemfile.lock file
http://pastie.org/private/tfbnteruyahmwfhtt26ea , and when I do 
    rake db:create --trace,
I get the following error trace.
http://pastie.org/private/vz6gzalof9wywhzfbk0ixg
 How can i fix this problem? Changing gem versions is not an option, since this file is already working with other developers.

Comment: Check database.yml to make sure you're using the correct adapter (mysql2)?

Comment: yes, i was using the adapter mysql and not mysql2, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check database.yml to make sure you're using the mysql2 adapter instead of mysql.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running Snow Leopard try to do the following

Uninstall mysql gem:

`sudo gem uninstall mysql`

Install gem with correct flags

`sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386" gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config`

P.S: Also check that you're running MySQL 5.1 and not 5.5 because there were some troubles with it so it is recommended to downgrade to 5.1.